# Calculate Vector of Ray Determined by Pixel Coordinate

Tags: python, opencv, camera, linear-algebra

I am attempting to calculate the vector of a ray passing through a pixel on the image plane of my camera.

I calibrated my camera. Setup a checkerboard which I define the center to be (0,0,0) and use cv2.solvePnP(). Using the rvec and tvec from cv2.solvePnP I can calculate the camera position in world coordinates by the following code.

```
_, rvecs, tvecs, _ = cv.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, new_mtx, dist)
                    
np_rodrigues = np.asarray(rvecs1[:,:],np.float64)
rmat1 = cv.Rodrigues(np_rodrigues)[0]
camera_position1 = -np.matrix(rmat1).T @ np.matrix(tvecs1)
```

The documentation for solvePnP() (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d1f/calib3d_solvePnP.html) references the equation below. I have been trying to invert it without much success to solve for world coordinates. After some more research on here, many posts have said it is not possible, due to the fact that a pixel does not map to a specific X,Y,Z coordinate, but it does map to a ray, which is what I need to find.

[image]

For what it is worth, I have come up with a really ugly solution using the FOV and image size to get angles along the x and y axis of my image which I use to determine a vector, but I know that this is not going to be very accurate for many reasons.

There has to be a way to do this using the information I have! Right?

Comment: Have a look at https://nicolas.burrus.name/oldstuff/kinect_calibration/ where he computes P3D you will see the ray in camera space (with all possible depth values). Just transform that P3D with the extrinsics to get the ray in your world space.

Comment: And make sure to undistort befire using pixel positions x_d and y_d.

Comment: @Micka thank you SOOOO much for smacking some sense into me. I am so annoyed I missed the fact that the focal length in the intrinsic camera matrix is in pixels. This is literally simple trig! You are a life saver.